# SQL: Copy some field values to another record inside the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a table with that has about 100 records that serve as template and over 10000 copy records backreferencing to the originals. I need to reinitialize a field in the copies from their corresponding originals but cannot figure out why I cannot reference the outside field from the subquery.

Example table ([SQLFiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb9fb/2)):

```
ID   OriginalID    String
----------------------------
1    NULL          original 1
2    NULL          original 2
3    1             copy of 1
4    2             copy of 2
5    2             another copy of 2
```

Desired result:

```
1 no change
2 no change
3 string should change to 'original 1'
4 string should change to 'original 2'
5 string should change to 'original 2'
```

SQL I tried:

```
update data as target set target.string=(select string from 
(select string from data as source where source.id=target.originalid) as x);
```

Error:

```
Unknown column 'target.originalid' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: is this what you want so i can convert it to answer? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1cd52/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE data a
       INNER JOIN data b
          ON a.originalid = b.id
SET a.data = b.data
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c97e/1)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║ ID ║ ORIGINALID ║   STRING   ║
╠════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║  1 ║ (null)     ║ original 1 ║
║  2 ║ (null)     ║ original 2 ║
║  3 ║ 1          ║ original 1 ║
║  4 ║ 2          ║ original 2 ║
║  5 ║ 2          ║ original 2 ║
╚════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

You're receiving that error because a subquery only has access to it's immediate parent query's data.  Meaning your `SELECT string FROM () as x` has knowledge of `target.*`, but not the subquery.  BUT, you also can't select and write to the same table in a single query.

Though there's probably a fancier way to do this... I would suggest populating another table with this data, then just rename your 2 tables.

Answer (score 1):

If you try the following SQL you should find that it achieves your objective (hopefully):

```
UPDATE data
  SET String = c.String
  FROM data INNER JOIN data c ON c.ID = data.OriginalID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update  data d2 join data d1 on d1.Id = d2.OriginalId
set     d2.data = d1.data;
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
 UPDATE data d
       JOIN
         ( SELECT id, data
             FROM data
             WHERE originalid IS NULL
         ) AS do
  SET d.data = do.data
  WHERE d.originalid = do.id;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f7a3/1)